# Messages stuck in sendmail queue beyond confTO_QUEUERETURN lifetime

Tags: centos, email-server, sendmail, email

CentOS 5.x | SendMail

Hi Guys,

Messages are stuck in my server's /var/spool/mqueue/ folder beyond the lifetime I have specified in confTO_QUEUERETURN (5d).  Any idea why this could be? The file permissions appear fine; files in the mqueue folder show rights of:

```
-rw------- 1 root smmsp
```

This is causing an issue because the queues are slowly getting larger and larger.

Any thoughts?

-M

---

Additional information... I'm seeing the queue size consistently growing. maillog shows entries like:

```
grew WorkList for /var/spool/mqueue to 28000
```

Any thoughts?

---

Just thinking outloud -- could the queue runner not be completing it's job in time? Maybe I could check with **time sendmail -q -v**

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Although I have very little experience with CentOS, I do seem to recall seeing some flavor of linux that didn't have sendmail configured with a queue runner by default.  I would be curious to see if your old messages are removed after running 'sendmail -q'.  If that's the case, then I think you just need to configure your queue runner to run periodically.